# Counting work days between two dates in C

Tags: c

I am writing a code in C with two functions.

The first (`WorkDay`) takes a date and says if it is a working day (`return 1`) or not (`return 0`). I think the first function is OK, although it could be better, but it is working. It includes weekends and public holidays in my country.

The problem comes with the second function (`CountWorkDays`). It should take two dates and say if they are correct (`return 1`) and in that case also say how many working days is among them, including the entered dates (`cnt=`). If the dates aren't correct (first is bigger than second etc.), there is `return 0`. I've tried to make a helping function `next_day()`, but I am pretty sure it is wrong. Can you help me with the second function please?
I cannot use `<time.h>` and I put there some asserts, which I am testing the function with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>

int WorkDay ( int y, int m, int d )
{
int h, day;
h= (d + floor(((m+1)*26)/10) + y + floor(y/4) + 6*floor(y/100) + floor(y/400));
day=h%7;

if ((y%4!=0) && m==2 && d==29)
    return 0;
else if (((y%4==0 || y%400==0) && (y%100!=0 || y%4000!=0)) && m==2 && d==29)
{

    if (day==2 || day==3 || day==4 || day==1 || day==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
else if ((d==1 && m==1) || (d==1 && m==5) || (d==8 && m==5) || (d==5 && m==7) || (d==6 && m==7) ||  (d==28 && m==9) || (d==28 && m==10) || (d==17 && m==11) || (d==24 && m==12) || (d==25 && m==12) || (d==26 && m==12) || day==0 || day==1 || (m==1 && (d>31 || d<1)) || (m==2 && (d>29 || d<1)) || (m==3 && (d>31 || d<1)) || (m==4 && (d>30 || d<1)) || (m==5 && (d>31 || d<1)) || (m==6 && (d>30 || d<1)) || (m==7 && (d>31 || d<1)) || (m==8 && (d>31 || d<1)) || (m==9 && (d>30 || d<1)) || (m==10 && (d>31 || d<1)) || (m==11 && (d>30 || d<1)) || (m==12 && (d>31 || d<1)) || y<2000 || m>12 || m<1)
    return 0;
else if (day==2 || day==3 || day==4 || day==5 || day==6)
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
}


int next_day()
{
int y1, m1, d1;
static int days_in_month[] = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
unsigned short day_counter;

    d1 += 1; day_counter++;
    if (d1 > days_in_month[m1])
        {
        d1 = 1;
        m1 += 1;
            if (m1 > 12)
            {
            m1 = 1;
            y1 += 1;
            if (((y1%4==0 || y1%400==0) && (y1%100!=0 || y1%4000!=0)))
                {
                days_in_month[2] = 29;
                }
            else
                {
                days_in_month[2] = 28;
                }
            }
        }
return 0;
}

int CountWorkDays ( int y1, int m1, int d1,
                int y2, int m2, int d2,
                int * cnt )
{
int i,x;
if ( (m1==1 && (d1>31 || d1<1)) || (m1==2 && (d1>29 || d1<1)) || (m1==3 && (d1>31 || d1<1)) || (m1==4 && (d1>30 || d1<1)) || (m1==5 && (d1>31 || d1<1)) || (m1==6 && (d1>30 || d1<1)) || (m1==7 && (d1>31 || d1<1)) || (m1==8 && (d1>31 || d1<1)) || (m1==9 && (d1>30 || d1<1)) || (m1==10 && (d1>31 || d1<1)) || (m1==11 && (d1>30 || d1<1)) || (m1==12 && (d1>31 || d1<1)) || y1<2000 || m1>12 || m1<1 ||(m2==1 && (d2>31 || d2<1)) || (m2==2 && (d2>29 || d2<1)) || (m2==3 && (d2>31 || d2<1)) || (m2==4 && (d2>30 || d2<1)) || (m2==5 && (d2>31 || d2<1)) || (m2==6 && (d2>30 || d2<1)) || (m2==7 && (d2>31 || d2<1)) || (m2==8 && (d2>31 || d2<1)) || (m2==9 && (d2>30 || d2<1)) || (m2==10 && (d2>31 || d2<1)) || (m2==11 && (d2>30 || d2<1)) || (m2==12 && (d2>31 || d2<1)) || y2<2000 || m2>12 || m2<1 || y2>y1 || (y1==y2 && m2>m1) || (y1==y2 && m1==m2 && d2>d1) )
    return 0;
else
{
while (y1!=y2 && m1!=m2 && d1!=d2)
{
while (next_day())
    {
    if (WorkDay( y1, m1, d1 ) == 1)
        i=0;
        x=i++;
    }
}
*cnt=x;
return 1;
}
}

int main ( int argc, char * argv [] )
{
  int cnt;
  assert ( WorkDay ( 2016, 11, 11 ) );
  assert ( ! WorkDay ( 2016, 11, 12 ) );
  assert ( CountWorkDays ( 2016, 11,  1,
                       2016, 11, 30, &cnt ) == 1
       && cnt == 21 );
  assert ( CountWorkDays ( 2001,  1,  1,
                       2015,  2, 29, &cnt ) == 0 );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Haven't seen that variant of Zeller's congruence before: looks a lot simpler than the original.  Watch for rounding errors on the floor((m+1)*26)/10) bit.  I have had to add .0001 on many 32-bit machine implementations.

Comment: Maybe you should add either 1 or 2 to your formula to make day 0 either Sunday or Monday instead of Saturday

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in next_day() and CountWorkDays().

1. next_day() is using local variables d1, m1 and y1. It is calculating next day of some random day.
2. In CountWorkDays(), you are not incrementing d1, m1, y1.

**Solution:**

1. Modify next_day() to receive a day as input and return next day as output.

   > ```
   > int next_day(int *d, int *m, int *y)
   > {
   >     /* Use current day to start. */
   >     int y1 = *y;
   >     int m1 = *m;
   >     int d1 = *d;
   >
   >    /* Your code to find next day. Remove day_counter here as it is unnecessary.*/
   >
   >    /* Return next day. */
   >    *y = y1;
   >    *m = m1;
   >    *d = d1;
   >    return 0;
   > }
   > ```
2. In CountWorkDays() call next_day with d1, m1, y1 as below.

> ```
> else
> {
>     while (1)
>     {
>         if (y1!=y2 && m1!=m2 && d1!=d2) //Check if end day is reached.
>         {
>             if (WorkDay( y1, m1, d1 ) == 1)
>                 x++; //At the beginning initialize x to 0.
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             break;
>         }
>
>         next_day(&d1, &m1, &y1); //Get the next day.
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: @alk I updated my answer. Basically i want next_day() to return next day of any given day.

Comment: Thank you for explanation and the code! But the asserts for `WorkDay` still don't work :( I am a beginner in C and I don't know what else should I fix.

Comment: @anonym: I am not able to understand your logic. Add comments in your code, people here might help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
int CountWorkDays(int y1, int m1, int d1, int y2, int m2, int d2, int * cnt)
{
    int i, x;
    if( (m1 == 1 && (d1>31 || d1<1)) || (m1 == 2 && (d1>29 || d1<1)) || (m1 == 3 && (d1>31 || d1<1)) || (m1 == 4 && (d1>30 || d1<1)) || (m1 == 5 && (d1>31 || d1<1)) || (m1 == 6 && (d1>30 || d1<1)) || (m1 == 7 && (d1>31 || d1<1)) || (m1 == 8 && (d1>31 || d1<1)) || (m1 == 9 && (d1>30 || d1<1)) || (m1 == 10 && (d1>31 || d1<1)) || (m1 == 11 && (d1>30 || d1<1)) || (m1 == 12 && (d1>31 || d1<1)) || y1<2000 || m1>12 || m1<1 || 
        (m2 == 1 && (d2>31 || d2<1)) || (m2 == 2 && (d2>29 || d2<1)) || (m2 == 3 && (d2>31 || d2<1)) || (m2 == 4 && (d2>30 || d2<1)) || (m2 == 5 && (d2>31 || d2<1)) || (m2 == 6 && (d2>30 || d2<1)) || (m2 == 7 && (d2>31 || d2<1)) || (m2 == 8 && (d2>31 || d2<1)) || (m2 == 9 && (d2>30 || d2<1)) || (m2 == 10 && (d2>31 || d2<1)) || (m2 == 11 && (d2>30 || d2<1)) || (m2 == 12 && (d2>31 || d2<1)) || y2<2000 || m2>12 || m2<1 || 
        y2>y1 || (y1 == y2 && m2>m1) || (y1 == y2 && m1 == m2 && d2>d1))
        ...
        x++;
```

Your logic is wrong and redundant. You need to check **only once** if day is less than 1. You are checking at least 20 times. Then you check it again another 20 times in another function. You repeat that for `d2`. This makes your code unreadable and prone to errors.

Also you are not initializing variables. The starting value of `x` is undefined. Put `int x = 0;` and `i = 0;`

Later you have:

```
i=0;
x=i++;
```

You could rewrite this as `x = 1`. But you probably mean to write `x++`

Here it seems you are checking for holidays:

```
else if((
    d == 1 && m == 1) || 
    (d == 1 && m == 5) || 
    (d == 8 && m == 5) || 
    (d == 5 && m == 7) || 
    (d == 6 && m == 7) || 
    (d == 28 && m == 9) || 
    (d == 28 && m == 10) || 
    (d == 17 && m == 11) || 
    (d == 24 && m == 12) || 
    (d == 25 && m == 12) || 
    (d == 26 && m == 12) ||
```

This type of coding is not wrong, but it's not practical either. I would put the holidays in a structure:

```
struct holidays_t
{
    int day, month;
};

struct holidays_t holidays[] = { 
    { 1 , 1 },
    { 1 , 5 },
    ...
};
```

Then loop through `holidays` array to see if the dates match. If you have not learned structures yet, then put the days and months in two different arrays. Example:

```
int holiday_days[]={1,1,...};
int holiday_months[]={1,5,...};
```

Your formula for weekday is wrong. You need to fix that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int is_leap_year(int y)
{
    return (y % 4) == 0 && y % 100 != 0 || (y % 400 == 0 && y != 4000);
}

int get_days_in_month(int year, int month)
{
    const int days_in_month[] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
    if(month >= 1 && month <= 12)
    {
        int days = days_in_month[month - 1];
        if(month == 2 && is_leap_year(year))
            days++;
        return days;
    }
    return 0;
}

int is_date_valid(int year, int month, int day)
{
    if(get_days_in_month(year, month) == 0) return 0;
    return day >= 1 && day <= get_days_in_month(year, month);
}

//this is wrong: ***************************************************
int get_weekday(int y, int m, int d)
{
    int h = (d + floor(((m + 1) * 26) / 10) + y + floor(y / 4) + 6 * floor(y / 100) + floor(y / 400));
    int weekday = h % 7;
    return weekday;
}

struct holidays_t
{
    int day, month;
};

int is_holiday(int m, int d)
{
    const struct holidays_t holidays[] = {
        { 1 , 1 },
        { 1 , 5 },
        { 8 , 5 },
        { 5 , 7 },
        { 6 , 7 },
        { 28, 9 },
        { 28, 10 },
        { 17, 11 },
        { 24, 12 },
        { 25, 12 },
        { 26, 12 },
    };

    int count = sizeof(holidays) / sizeof(holidays[0]);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
        if(holidays[i].month == m && holidays[i].day == d)
            return 1;
    return 0;
}

int CountWorkDays(int y1, int m1, int d1, int y2, int m2, int d2, int *ptr)
{
    int count = 0;
    *ptr = 0;
    if(!is_date_valid(y1, m1, d1)) return 0;
    if(!is_date_valid(y2, m2, d2)) return 0;

    int y, m, d;
    for(y = y1; y <= y2; y++)
    {
        int month_start = 1;
        int month_end = 12;

        if(y == y1) month_start = m1;
        if(y == y2) month_end = m2;

        for(m = month_start; m <= month_end; m++)
        {
            int day_start = 1;
            int day_end = get_days_in_month(y, m);

            if(y == y1 && m == m1) day_start = d1;
            if(y == y2 && m == m2) day_end = d2;

            for(d = day_start; d <= day_end; d++)
            {
                int test = 0;
                if(is_holiday(m, d))
                {
                    test = 1;
                    printf("holiday %d %d %d\n", y, m, d);
                }

                int weekday = get_weekday(y, m, d);
                if(weekday == 0 || weekday == 6)
                {
                    test = 1;
                    printf("weekend %d %d %d %s\n", y, m, d, (weekday == 0) ? "sunday" : "staurday");
                }

                if(!test)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    *ptr = count;

    //return success
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    CountWorkDays(2016, 1, 1, 2016, 12, 31, &count);
    printf("count %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I corrected it, but I still don't know how to figure out `cnt` (number of working days between two days), because before I had the `next_day` function in while cycle, but now I don't know what to put into the cycle. So I check `if(!is_date_valid...)` and then what?

Comment: Your formula for weekday is wrong, among other errors. Do you want me to fix everything for you?

Comment: I just wanted to know, which cycle should I use for counting `cnt`.

Comment: You are not counting anything. You `x=i++;` as I said before it just keeps setting `x = 1`. Then you set `*cnt = x`. Therefore `cnt` is always 1.